# Script for automating uninstall of 2007 and install of 2013

Tags: microsoft-office, automation, remote, vbscript, windows-task-scheduler

I am an IT sysadmin, managing around 300 PCs, and my requirement is to Uninstall office 2007 and Install Office 2013 initially on 40 PCs, my organization uses Tanium to do the automated deployment of microsoft updates et cetera, so I had emailed them asking their help to create a script, but they rejected the request telling that they cannot create script for 40 users. It is quite time consuming to install it manually, Is there any automated way through which I can do it?

My idea was to create a scheduled (elevated) task to be run on each PCs on a particular day when its locked. But the script would require admin rights, and only the sysadmin have the admin rights and the users' PC in which I would require the tasks to be run would be on standard accounts.

I am quite a newbie to scripting and stuffs. So is there anyway to remotely run an elevated scheduled task on multiple PCs in standard account in a domain?

Or, do you have any other smarter alternative to uninstall 2007 and install 2013 on multiple PCs? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe using a .bat file to run the uninstallers?

Answer (score 0):

This question might be better suited for **ServerFault**. I would post the question there and delete this one, personally. But yes, it's possible write a batch file script to Run As domain admin:
 `runas /env /user:Administrator@domain.com program.msi`